# VMware Workstation overrides VS2008 hotkeys

Tags: visual-studio, vmware, hotkeys

I recently installed VMware Workstation on my computer, and it is causing me some trouble. I'm used to pressing F6 to build in VS2008, but Workstation keeps replacing the hotkey for build with Ctrl+Alt+B, and assigning its own hotkey to F6. Every time I change the hotkey back and restart VS, VMware messes it up again. How do I get my hotkey back without uninstalling Workstation?

Comment: It gets even better with VmWare7.01 whatever version. Ctrl+R resets machine... -_-

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest asking over on the VMware forums, there are quite a few threads with people complaining about it messing with the VS2005 hotkeys.

Answer (score 0):

VMWare's default key combo for ungrabbing the keyboard/mouse input from the guest OS is Control + Alt.  You can change the key combo to something else (ctrl + win perhaps?) from the edit->Preferences->Hot Keys  tab.